# Filter two arrays to ensure that if category is x it is unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table as follows

```
|Claim| |ID CD|

|:---|  |:---|

|757|    |59| 

|757|    |59|

|757|    |60|

|758|    |59|

|758|    |59|
```

I am trying to create a formula, that looks at the claim column and if it has ID 59, make sure that it is a unique id for that claim. If not show the claim id.

So for the above the output in the cell would be

757

Edit : Solved

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(r_trans_clm_id,r_jur_cd="59")),FILTER(r_trans_clm_id,r_jur_cd<>"59"),FILTER(r_trans_clm_id,r_jur_cd<>"59"),"",0),"No Federal Duplicates")
```

If error is introduced due to if there is no duplicates a #calc error occurs.

Comment: What about 758 in your example? Also, when referring to the `claim column`, you are looking at value in the `ID CD` column. Your wording is not very precise, which may create confusions for others.

Comment: 758 has a unique id for that claim... 59. The wording is fine.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you wish to list all unique claims with ID CD 59. If you have office365 this is easily done using UNIQUE and FILTER.

Comment: Correct, but I only want it to trigger if ID CD 59 is not the only ID CD for the Claim. For example Claim 757 has two id codes 59 and 60. Therefore the column with the array formula will spill 757 and another other claim that has code 59 and another id.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is actually quite interesting after knowing what OP wants to achieve. My solution (using **Excel 365**) is a bit complex, and I really want to see if there is a simpler version...

Suppose your `claim` column is named **List_Claim**, and your `ID CD` column is named **List_ID**,

In the cell that you want to the return the claims that have more than one `ID CD`, enter the following formula:

```
=LET(x,--(LEN(UNIQUE(IF(List_Claim=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(List_Claim)),List_ID,"")))>0),y,ARRAYTOTEXT(TRANSPOSE(x),1),z,"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(y,2,LEN(y)-2),",",""),0,""),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>",FILTER(UNIQUE(List_Claim),NOT(FILTERXML(z,"//s[node()]")=1)))
```

It will return the results in a vertical array.

Here is a little breakdown of what I've done:

1. using **LET** function, I have declared the following:

name: `x`
formula: `--(LEN(UNIQUE(IF(List_Claim=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(List_Claim)),List_ID,"")))>0)` to check if each claim has a matching `ID CD`, if so, returns 1, else 0. So if a claim has more than one matching `ID CD`, you will have at least two `1` in the array for that claim, such as {1,1,0,0,0}, otherwise, you should only have one `1` in the array such as {0,0,1,0,0}

name: `y`
formula: `=ARRAYTOTEXT(TRANSPOSE(x),1)` to convert the array to a text string, such as {1,1,0,0,0;0,0,1,0,0}

name: `z`
formula" `="<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(y,2,LEN(y)-2),",",""),0,""),";","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` to modify the text string so I can use the [FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) function to convert it back into arrays, such as {11;1}

2. in the last argument of the **LET** function, enter the final calculation `=FILTER(UNIQUE(List_Claim),NOT(FILTERXML(z,"//s[node()]")=1))`

This will filter all unique claims and only show claims with more than one `ID CD`.

[image: example solution]

Comment: I actually figured it out, i'll post my version of the solution in the main body.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve is this is to add a index column that combines the `Claim` and `ID CD` values into one. Then you can check for other duplicate values in the index column.

[image: Screen shot of formulas]

First add an index column that creates a new value that combines the Claim and ID CD.

The formula in `D4` in my example is `=B4&"."&C4`.

Now you will want to check to see if the value in the index column matches any other values.  I use `COUNTIF` for this.

If the count is greater than one I use the `IF` function to return the `Claim` value otherwise it returns NULL.

The formula in `F4` is

```
=IF(
    COUNTIF($D$4:$D$8,D4)>1,
      B4,
      ""
   )
```